# Error when attempting to parse xhr response text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, fine-uploader

I have downloaded the plugin "Fine Uploader" and initialize it that (according to the examples of the official website) all good except that when wanting to upload the file will not let me, giving me the following error:

> [Fine Uploader 5.2.1] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token <)
>       fine-uploader.js:249 
>       qq.logfine-uploader.js:1837
>       qq.basePublicApi.logfine-uploader.js:695 
>       qq.bindfine-uploader.js:7845 
>       parseResponsefine-uploader.js:7828 
>       onUploadOrChunkCompletefine-uploader.js:7789 
>       xhr.onreadystatechange

this is the only thing I changed from the demos shown on the official website

```
var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({ 
    element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"), 
    template: 'qq-template-gallery', 
    request: { endpoint: '../proyecciones' }, 
    thumbnails: { 
        placeholders: {
            waitingPath: '../fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png', 
            notAvailablePath: '../fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png' 
        } 
    }, 
    validation: { 
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'] 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you give us some code please?

Comment: this is the only thing I changed from the demos shown on the official website         
var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
template: 'qq-template-gallery',
            request: {
                endpoint: '../proyecciones'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {waitingPath: '../fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '../fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
}
},
validation: {
 allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
}
 });

Comment: but the link attached here where my file I'm working, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4aoLRav8fPGbjduVUpUaXY0Skk/view?usp=sharing, 
there will excuse my English

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your server is not returning a valid JSON response to one of Fine Uploader's requests. In fact, your server is not returning JSON at all. Just a guess, but the response appears to be HTML. You can read more about returning responses for traditional endpoints at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html.

Comment: He is right that it is probably HTML. My guess is that you have an error somewhere and your server is displaying an HTML error page, probably 404 not found or 503 internal server error.

Comment: @ray, can you please explain what should be in the end point controller? I am returning a response, but do not know how to handle the incoming file and how to upload it. I'm using codeignitor framework.